# Unable to generate 'sas' Token using angular-azure-blob-service

Tags: angular, azure, blob, azure-blob-storage

```js
 if (fileUpload !== null) {
      const baseUrl = this.blob.generateBlobUrl(Config,'testBlobUpload');
      this.config = {
        baseUrl: baseUrl,
        sasToken: Config.sas,
        blockSize: 1024 * 64, // OPTIONAL, default value is 1024 * 32
        file: fileUpload.nativeFile,
        complete: () => {
          console.log('Transfer completed !');
        },
        error: () => {
          console.log('Error !');
        },
        progress: (percent) => {
          //this.percent = percent;
        }
      };
      this.blob.upload(this.config);
    }
    
    
    export const Config: UploadParams = {
        sas:'?sv=2017-07-29&sr=b&sig=q80fVo0wp8SVmTcgae%2BjceUPfKjE3Eb2MYbkClm8EqQ%3D&st=2018-03-06T13%3A49%3A33Z&se=2018-11-01T13%3A49%3A33Z&sp=racw',
        storageAccount: 'vldevstoragefuncapp.blob.core.windows.net/vl2songs',
        containerName: 'vl2songs'
        //?sv=2017-07-29&sr=b&sig=QXVl6BcV47WiOPbM8CeNhmGpC%2FNslyN7qnI%2BopLuXyg%3D&st=2018-03-06T11%3A46%3A49Z&se=2018-11-01T11%3A46%3A50Z&sp=rw
      }
```

Using Angular5 for uploading media files on Azure blob using angular-azure-blob-service, I am facing issue with generating the 'sas' Token, If anyone Used help me, Thanks

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VuHt0.png)

[image]

Comment: Can you share your code for generating SAS Token?

Comment: @GauravMantri I have that, Sharing link i am using https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-azure-blob-service

You will see, Lib don't have code for generating the 'sas' Token

Comment: This library needs SAS token. You will need to generate it elsewhere and then use it in your code.

Comment: Does it means, I need to create a separate API for This? then need to use that for this Lib, right.

Comment: You're absolutely correct.

Comment: @GauravMantri  Make a separate API for getting SAS Token and making call to Upload then its showing me some CORS setting issue on Azure Blob.



Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 403.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174350/discussion-between-vivek-shukla-and-gaurav-mantri).

Comment: Please read the CORS section in the NPM link you shared. Make sure that you have configured the CORS rules properly.

Comment: @GauravMantri Done that, Thanks CORS fixed now, now getting one new error see --PUT https://vldevstoragefuncapp.blob.core.windows.net/vl2songs.blob.core.windows.net/vl2songs/testBlobUpload?sv=2017-07-29&sr=b&sig=q80fVo0wp8SVmTcgae%2BjceUPfKjE3Eb2MYbkClm8EqQ%3D&st=2018-03-06T13%3A49%3A33Z&se=2018-11-01T13%3A49%3A33Z&sp=racw&comp=block&blockid=YmxvY2stMDAwMDAw 403 (Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.)

Comment: @GauravMantri Is this related to SAS Token or baseURL ?

Comment: It's very hard to comment without looking at your code. I suggest you edit your question and include the code you are using.

Comment: @GauravMantri I have added Image of setting info for request, If need more, Could you please Have a Chat with me.

Comment: Please do not add image. Instead add code. It's easier to work that way.

Comment: @GauravMantri I have posted Code, You can have look

Comment: Can you try by changing the following line of code `storageAccount: 'vldevstoragefuncapp.blob.core.windows.net/vl2songs'` to `storageAccount: 'vldevstoragefuncapp'`?

Comment: @GauravMantri Now showing error 

PUT https://vldevstoragefuncapp.blob.core.windows.net/vl2songs/testBlobUpload?sv=2017-07-29&sr=b&sig=9SN%2B01%2FVmjdle9BuMkTAwECIXzqXrpcwvs77F3PYY8c%3D&st=2018-03-07T07%3A13%3A48Z&se=2018-11-02T07%3A13%3A48Z&sp=racw&comp=block&blockid=YmxvY2stMDAwMDAw 403 (Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.)

Comment: Can you share a link to the code for this package (it should be on Github or some place)? Let me go through the code for that and see what it is trying to do.

Comment: @GauravMantri https://github.com/Gullfaxi171/angular-azure-blob-service

Comment: @GauravMantri If it possible could you connect or look my Screen please, its very priority work for me.

Comment: Vivek....Unfortunately it doesn't work that way. However, please upload your entire source code somewhere (remove the secret information if any) and share that link. I will take a look when I have some time.

Comment: @GauravMantri Its a large Project with Different Endpoints, I check with lead but not get permission for this, Sorry, looking we are very close, Is there any other way ?

Comment: In that case, please create a small project with just this functionality and share that.

Comment: @GauravMantri Thanks I will do that, In Case if not fix today

Answer (score 0):

To generat the SAS token in Angular 2+ you need to install - [create-hmac](https://www.npmjs.com/package/create-hmac)

```
npm i create-hmac
```

need to insert to index.html

```
<head>
  ...

  <script>
    var global = global || window;
    var Buffer = Buffer || [];
    var process = process || {
      env: { DEBUG: undefined },
      version: []
    };
  </script>
</head>
```

to genrate token -

```
public generateSasToken(resourceUri: string, signingKey: string, policyName: string, expiresInMins: number) {
    resourceUri = encodeURIComponent(resourceUri);
    let expires = (Date.now() / 1000) + expiresInMins * 60;
    expires = Math.ceil(expires);
    const toSign = resourceUri + '\n' + expires;

    // Use crypto
    const createHmac = require('create-hmac');
    const Buffer = require('buffer').Buffer;
    const hmac = createHmac('sha256', Buffer.from(signingKey, 'base64'));
    hmac.update(toSign);
    const base64UriEncoded = encodeURIComponent(hmac.digest('base64'));

    // Construct authorization string
    let token = 'SharedAccessSignature sr=' + resourceUri + '&sig='
      + base64UriEncoded + '&se=' + expires;
    if (policyName) {
      token += '&skn=' + policyName;
    }
    return token;
}
```